# Oracle Timestamp Difference

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have a DB table (Oracle) like below:

```
ID             STATUS             TIMESTAMP
--             ------             ---------
1              NEW                30-JAN-15 08.11.11.803384000 PM
2              NEW                30-JAN-15 08.11.13.606681000 PM 
1              COMPLETED          30-JAN-15 08.11.15.997794000 PM
2              COMPLETED          30-JAN-15 08.11.16.469299000 PM
```

I want to achieve two things:

1. Timestamp difference for each id from status new to complete
2. Avg time between new to complete for all id's between new to complete

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there only 1 entry for a `New` or `Completed` status for every unique `id`?

Comment: yes. 1 entry for new and 1 entry for completed for each id

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two rows for each id and "new" comes before "complete", then you can just do this to get the difference for each id:

```
select id, max(timestamp) - min(timestamp)
from dbtable t
group by id;
```

Or the related query to get the average:

```
select avg(diff)
from (select id, max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) as diff
      from dbtable t
      group by id
     ) t;
```

The differences are measured in days and fractional parts thereof.

Comment: Second query works fine. though i get a error on the first one. ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT ID
, ( TO_TIMESTAMP(NEWTS, 'DD-Mon-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM') - TO_TIMESTAMP(COMTS, 'DD-Mon-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM')) DIFF
FROM (select 
MIN(case when status='NEW'
 THEN TIMESTAMP
end) NEWTS,
MIN(case when status='COMPLETED'
 THEN TIMESTAMP
end) COMTS
, ID
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID) A
```

You could then do an `AVG` on this query to get your 2nd answer

Comment: I am not well versed in plSql, so the `to_TIMESTAMP` logic might be a little off, please verify that.

Answer (score 0):

This returns difference in minutes.

```
p.s : not tested


SELECT N.ID,
(24*60)*(C.TIMESTAMP - N.TIMESTAMP) AS DIFF_IN_MINUTES
FROM
(SELECT ID, TIMESTAMP
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE STATUS = 'NEW'
)N
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ID, TIMESTAMP
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE STATUS = 'COMPLETED'
)C
ON N.ID = C.ID
```